# По какой причине не подключаются стили?

Tags: php, битрикс

header.php

```html
<?php if (!defined("B_PROLOG_INCLUDED") || B_PROLOG_INCLUDED != true) die(); ?>
<?php
use Bitrix\Main\Page\Asset;
?>

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <title><?php
        $APPLICATION->ShowTitle();
        ?> </title>
    <?php
    Asset::getInstance()->addCss(SITE_TEMPLATE_PATH . "/src/css/bootstrap.css");
    Asset::getInstance()->addCss(SITE_TEMPLATE_PATH . "/src/css/style.css");
    ?>
</head>

<body>
<!--Навигационное меню-->
<div class="container">
    <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-dark bg-dark">
        <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">
            <img src="src/img/navLogo.png">
        </a>
        <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarSupportedContent"
                aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
            <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
        </button>

        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
            <ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto">
                <li class="nav-item dropdown">
                    <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="navbarDropdown" role="button"
                       data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
                        Наши контакты
                    </a>
                    <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdown">
                        <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Как с нами связаться?</a>
                        <div class="dropdown-divider"></div>
                        <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Где нас найти?</a>

                    </div>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </nav>
</div>
```

Скажите, что я не так делаю?

Comment: выведите на странице SITE_TEMPLATE_PATH."src/css/style.css", может слеш где потерялся

Comment: @ЕвгенийПлатов Поправил код, убрал cdn бутстрапа, пробую подключить локально, однако эффекта не возымело

Comment: К сожалению битрикс ничего не пишет если не находит указанный файл, я в таком случае вывожу путь на странице. Если файл по этому пути действительно существует, то можно попробовать сбросить кэш, возможно причина в этом

Answer (score 0):

В данном конкретном случае, просмотрев код страницы, нашел отсутствие тега .
Указание после открытия тега  $APPLICATION->ShowHead(); решило проблему, которая заключалась в отсутствии блока  в структуре DOM-дерева